# Aggregating daily sampling evidence into a monthly estimate

Tags: time-series, confidence-interval, sampling, small-sample, aggregation

Suppose there's a business process that's sampled daily for quality review purposes, i.e., a population of items is generated in daily batches, and randomly sampled every day to identify production errors. Sampling capacity constraints are such that the sampling rate is rather small, say around 2 out of a population of 50 items. This means that no significant statistical estimate can be performed of a daily basis, since it would produce horrible margin of errors at any practical confidence level.

A simple alternative would be re-organizing the sampling process to sample at random over a longer time period, e.g., 100 days. Suppose that the number of items produced every day is fairly constant, sampling 2 over 50 every day has the same resource demands than sampling 200 over 5000 items over a 100 day window. This suddenly yields much stronger statistics without the need of tinkering with statistical assumptions. The drawback is having to wait 100 days for the 5000 items to be produced, and only then starting the sampling and quality review work. This introduces a big lead time between the presence of production errors and the org's capability to acknowledge it and react accordingly.

Is there any way to aggregate/compound this daily sampling evidence into estimates holding over a longer time-horizon, i.e., weekly/monthly/quarterly/yearly? My intuition suggests that just treating the daily samples as independent and pooling the results together requires assuming that the distribution of production errors is independent of time -- something that hardly holds and is probably also hard to test for.

This sounds like a common problem that must have been studied already -- at least I know that standards like ISO 2859-1 exist to tackle similar challenges. It's not clear to me though how they address this time (in)dependence issue on the distribution of errors, and how they can be used to derive standard sampling statistics like margin of errors and intervals of confidence.

What's your take on the problem?